# Запуск метода, при нажатии клавишы

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть приложение, созданное библиотекой kivy, я хочу, чтобы при нажатии клавишы, запускался метод в классе `MainApp`, а точнее `start_tr`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import pyautogui
import keyboard
from kivy.clock import Clock
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout(size=(1000, 1000))
        button=Button(text='Start',on_press=self.start_tr,pos_hint={'center_x': .4, 'center_y': .4},size_hint=(.13, .13))
        button2 = Button(text='Stop', on_press=self.stop_tr,pos_hint={'center_x': .6, 'center_y': .4},size_hint=(.13, .13))
        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(button2)
        return layout

    def click_loop(self,*args):
        print(1)
        #pyautogui.click(pyautogui.position())
    def start_tr(self,*args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.click_loop, 1)
    def stop_tr(self,*args):
        Clock.unschedule(self.click_loop)
    keyboard.on_press_key('y', start_tr())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Я пробовал таким способом, но вылетает ошибка:

```
TypeError: MainApp.start_tr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было просто убрать `()`

---

**Исправь на данную схему:**

```
keyboard.on_press_key('y', start_tr)
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно сработало, правда теперь вылетает AttributeError: 'KeyboardEvent' object has no attribute 'click_loop'